# CSS: nth-child(even) but not divisible by 3

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-selectors

I'm trying to add different styles to every even DIV so long as it's not divisible by 3. So the second div gets padding, the fourth div gets padding, but the sixth is skipped over. Is this possible with CSS only?

The reason I'm doing this is that I'm snapping from a two column grid, to a three column grid on desktop and I need to overwrite mobile styles.

I don't want to use JavaScript.

```
<div> 1 </div>
<div> 2 </div>
<div> 3 </div>
<div> 4 </div>
<div> 5 </div>
<div> 6 </div>
<div> 7 </div>


@include breakpoint(mobile-wide) {
    width: calc((2.5 / 6 * 100%) - 0rem + (2.5 / 6 * 0rem))
    float: left;
    margin-right: calc((0.5 / 6 * 100%) + 0rem + (0.5 / 6 * 0rem));
    &:nth-child(2n) {
      margin-right: 0;
      float: right;
}

@include breakpoint(desktop) {
    width: calc((3 / 12 * 100%) - 0rem + (3 / 12 * 0rem));
    float: left;
    margin-right: calc((1.5 / 12 * 100%) + 0rem + (1.5 / 12 * 0rem));
    &:nth-child(3){
     margin-right: 0;
     float: right;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your relevant code here enough to reproduce the situation or problem

Comment: if nothing else, do your even rule, then put in a every-3rd rule to override the even rule.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may exclude those with `:not()` selector, using `:nth-child(3n+3)`

```css
div:nth-child(even):not(:nth-child(3n+3)) {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

Here you go:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewbdm4so/)

This is achievable via the `:not` CSS selector like so:

`li:nth-child(2n):not(:nth-child(3n))`

Which produces the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Add the `padding` rule for every even element, and the padding reset to every sixth element. No need to complicate things.

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/cjvk8z6u/

Comment: @LcSalazar Do you know of an even element (or a number) that is divisible by 3 and that is not divisible by 6? Or do you know a number divisible by 6 that is not even and divisible by 3?

Comment: Hah, now my comment looks idiotic there all alone. :) Never mind, I'll leave it in case someone else wonders why I chose 6 instead of 3.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is fairly simple. You want to select the following sequence:

```
2, 4, 8, 10, 14, 16, ...
```

Notice any pattern? Try again:

```
2, 8, 14, ...
4, 10, 16, ...
```

This translates to two sequences: starting from 2 and 4, having a gap of 6; these can be represented by nth-child selector as follows:

```css
div {
  font: medium monospace;
}
div:nth-child(6n + 2),
div:nth-child(6n + 4) {
  background: #FC0;
}
```

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2*</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4*</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8*</div>
<div>9</div>
<div>10*</div>
<div>11</div>
<div>12</div>
<div>13</div>
<div>14*</div>
<div>15</div>
<div>16*</div>
<div>17</div>
<div>18</div>
<div>19</div>
<div>20*</div>
```